# Windows 7 does not recognise mouse or keyboard after hardware change

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, mouse

I just put my SSD (*Evo 340*) into a new PC: the new motherboard is a *Prime B350-Plus*, old one was a *ASUS P8H67*.

Now when booting Windows 7, it doesn't recognize my mouse nor my keyboard.

BIOS does recognize both. I can go to Safe Mode, but same problem.

I have tried:

- Rebooting with disconnected devices, plugging them in when in login screen
- Windows CD (does not recognize Mouse or Keyboard either)
- Other USB slots
- Disabling *Legacy USB support*
- Mouse and Keyboard do work with a Ubuntu Live CD (16.04 LTS)

At the moment, I don't know what else to do.

Comment: How about a Ubuntu LiveCD? Or a different mouse?

Comment: @someuser Different mouse doesn't work. Ubuntu Live CD i will try out, should have one lying around here. But how would that help my windows problem?

Comment: The peripherals should work if connected to the USB2.0 (Windows 7 has no native support for USB3.x). And you may need to install in UEFI mode with Secure Boot disabled. Windows 7 is NOT recommended for any current hardware anyway.

Comment: @MichaelBay Peripherals are connected to USB2.0.

Comment: @someuser Ok, Ubuntu Live CD seems to recognise both. Does that help me in any way?

Comment: @Fl.pf. Try adding the USB 3 drivers to the Windows 7 installation image you are using.  [Your motherboard supports Windows 7](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/PRIME-B350-PLUS/HelpDesk_Download/)

Comment: @Ramhound How would I do that?

Comment: I would simply use the [Intel tool](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/25476/Windows-7-USB-3-0-Creator-Utility)

Comment: There is only one Intel tool, that takes a Windows image, and adds USB 3 compatibility to it. I also linked to it.

Comment: Or reinstall Windows and let the installation process find the correct  drivers.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I can't reinstall Windows if the Windows CD doesn't recognise the mouse and keyboard. Well I ended up putting the SSD back into my old PC, upgrading it to Win10 and putting it back into the new one.  I think this is probably the best long term. Win7 would have probably started to make more and more problems now. Thanks for the help everybody.

Comment: I am surprised it worked for you as I believe the license won't transfer to a different motherboard.

Comment: @someuser new license. Also I think it does, you just have to connect your license to an Microsoft Online Account or something like that